# desktop simple viewer

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1

In order to develop an app remote desktop WP7, I started to with a desktop simple viewer and it works but the problem that not show all actions that I do in Server side, that's video in YouTube can show you my problem
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3q-FumfYsPQ&feature=youtu.be

I use socket connection and I decode and encode my data (images).

This is my code in WP7 client side

```
    void Conncet(string IP_Address)
    {

        client_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs()
        {
            RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP_Address), 4532)
        };
        socketEventArg.Completed += OnConncetCompleted;
        client_socket.ConnectAsync(socketEventArg);
    }
    void StartReceiving()
    {
            byte[] response = new byte[131072];
            SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            socketEventArg.Completed += OnReceiveCompleted;
            socketEventArg.SetBuffer(response, 0, response.Length);
            client_socket.ReceiveAsync(socketEventArg);
    }

    private void ViewReceivedImage(byte[] buffer)
    {
        try
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.SetSource(ms);
            MyImage.Source = bi;
            ms.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
        finally
        {
            StartReceiving();
        }
    }
```

This is my code in Server side (PC) sending images.

```
  void StartSending()
    {
        while (!stop)

            try
            {
                Image oldimage = scr.Get_Resized_Image(wToCompare, hToCompare, scr.GetDesktopBitmapBytes());
                //Thread.Sleep(1);
                Image newimage = scr.Get_Resized_Image(wToCompare, hToCompare, scr.GetDesktopBitmapBytes());

                byte[] buffer = scr.GetDesktop_ResizedBytes(wToSend, hToSend);

                float difference = scr.difference(newimage, oldimage);


                if (difference >= 1)
                {

                    SenderSocket.Send(buffer);
                }


            }
            catch (Exception) { }
    }
```

My question is how can I make the send and receive fast to show the PC screen in WP7 in +/- real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to find what's the bottleneck and speed that up. It could be that the network is not working fast enough. Using compression might be the answer.

It could be that the WP7 machine is not fast enough to show the images. Sending partial screen images or lower resolution might be a solution.

It could be that the windows machine is simply not grabbing the images fast enough. Chancing some code around might be the solution. Using partial updates could also help.

I would go for a solution where every update I would only send one corner (upper left, upper right, lower left, lower right) so the entire stack had to send/recieve smaller blobs of data.

Be aware that the simulator might add/remove some overhead and show non realistic performance. So don't optimize the code for the simulator (too much)

Comment: I would add lots of 'logging' code to see what steps are slow and on which side the slowness is occuring. It might be that the bottleneck in the current situation is simply the WP7 device not showing the images fast enough.

Comment: the problem how I can speed up??
I use it in the machine and the result is the same between 2 machine,
I also use it in different network and show me the same view

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're running out of bandwidth.

Sending full uncompressed images is a terrible idea, if you ask me, bandwidth-wise. A single RGB32, 800x480 image is approximately 1.15 megs in size, so to sustain, let's say 15 FPS, you'd need a [138 Mbit/s](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=15%2a3%2a800%2a480%20bytes%20in%20megabits) connection.

I'd suggest, on the server side, to only send the rectangles that have changed, and then send them compressed. One protocol that already does this is the [RFB protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RFB_protocol), most famously used in VNC.

Comment: The idea about send only that pixels that changed between the old image and the new image is really good, but how I ca send only that pixel and they're position in the image, that's a question.
And about compression, how I can do that with images?