# Error get image on WP7 fast

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

```
private void ViewReceivedImage(byte[] buffer)
    {
        try
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.SetSource(ms);
            MyImage.Source = bi;
            ms.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
        finally
        {
            StartReceiving();
        }
    }
```

I develop this code to get the image from PC screen and show it on WP7, and its work fine on WP7 emulator
[this the video that work on emulator](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCwsuj7Hcno)
but when I install the xap on WP7 device, it not show all the images, the refresh really fast that don't show only a the top part of image
I think maybe the hardware of WP7 really  slow in front of my PC.
If I will add a wait time, where can I put it, or if there are any solution?
I use tcp socket.

Comment: So is the WP7 client recieving `any` data form the PC? Is this a speed issue or is this a connectivity issue?

Comment: not any data, just image, maybe speed issue. The connection work great

Comment: Could you instead look at using something like RDP?

Comment: ...and I really hope that your production code doesn't swallow every exception as well...

Comment: possible duplicate of [desktop simple viewer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427580/desktop-simple-viewer)

Answer (score 2):

So try sending less data to speed it up

- only send half the number of frames
- send less colour data
- compress it before sending (Zip it or something along those lines).

Comment: Are we answering the right question though? Is it that the connection between the PC and the phone is not quick enough to recieve the data?

Comment: no, the data is receive right, but I think the shown images change very fast that can't show it right on WP7 device, maybe I think I need to add a waiting time like 1 second or less.